# Preventing Duplicate Items in list (sharepoint 2007)

Tags: content-editor-web-part, javascript, list, 2007

Is it possible to restrict, creation of duplicate list item in the Sharepoint 2007,
using Javascript in content editor webpart to validate when an list item is added?

Comment: Are you trying to have a unique column in the list item. How does this CEWP come into picture. Can you ellaborate the scenario?

Comment: I have a list, whenever an item is added to this list, the title should be unique; there shouldn't be list items with same title..

Comment: i understood the above , What are you trying to achieve using CEWP?

Comment: Custom code is the only way to guarantee this. JavaScript can be disabled or altered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list web service via JavaScript/jQuery and validate if an item exists.
I would prefer doing this on an event recevier (lot easier) but I guess you don't have a access to deploy code ?
here are some samples using JS http://darrenjohnstone.net/2007/05/28/querying-a-sharepoint-list-with-JavaScript/
and here using jQuery http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be trivial, but you can use javascript to carry out a web service call to lookup all items with the same title.

Have a look at the [SPServices JavaScript library on CodePlex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).